# Can Vista sidebar be pinned (locked in place)?

Tags: windows-vista, sidebar

Can Vista sidebar be pinned or locked in place?
I hate when I minimize all windows and sidebar disappears to and then I have to find and click icon. It would be perfect if sidebar can be locked so that it stays visible when I minimize all other windows.

I'm aware that sidebar can be set to be on top of other windows, but then it takes screen realestate.

Can single gadget be locked but not always on top of other windows?

Is there some keystroke combination that can bring sidebar to front?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keystroke combination: Win + Space key brings the sidebar and detached gadgets to the foreground.